# Windows capture screen

Tags: c++, windows, directx, screenshot

I am working on an app that captures an image from the screen and tries to stream this as video. I am planning the app to work on all windows computers. However, on my computer, right now the

```
CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hMainWindow, devBehaviorFlags, &d3dpp, &d3dDevice))
```

function fails. I have directx drivers. My concerns now are about whether using directx is a good way to capture the screen for an app to work on all windows machines.

My question is this :

Is directx the best way to capture screen on windows, or is there a better way? ( Maybe even cross platform ) Also is capturing screen and turning this into a video stream a good approach for such an app ?

Comment: Fails how?  Do you mean ``ID3DDevice9::CreateDevice`` Direct3D 9.0c is built into Windows XP Service Pack 2 or later and Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 or later versions of Windows. However, using Direct3D 9 on Windows Vista or later is going to result in appcompat behavior and you'll also need to cope with the Desktop Windows Composition Manager which has different behavior on Windows Vista vs. Windows 7 vs. Windows 8.x. You also have to content with full-screen vs. windowed apps.

Comment: It gives   'hrresult 0x8876086c HRESULT'
Somehow acts like I dont have directx installed. But dxdiag says I have directx11. I am kinda confused.

Comment: How do you initialize directx? Show code. Which version?

Comment: If DirectX wasn't installed, you'd have never gotten an ``ID3DDevice9`` instance. As I said, unless you are dealing with ancient Windows (aka Windows ME or NT 4) you already have DirectX 9.0c. That HRESULT is `` D3DERR_INVALIDCALL`` which probably means something else is wrong with your call

Comment: I dont think you are right with INVALIDCALL. I know you are very knowledgable at this, but this error is also seen by people who has a bad driver in their systems all through the internet. Besides same code works in another pc. I just tested it :)